# How to edit fixed link text in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms, links

Does anybody know if its possible to edit the link text in the confirmation form of a Google Form?

Having enabled the summary of responses, I have the following link text which is set by the form:

['See previous responses'](http://www.google.co.uk)
'[Submit another response](http://www.google.co.uk)'

Does anybody know of a way to edit this text? I would like it to read

'See this months responses'

and ideally I would remove the 'Submit another response' link.

Answer (score 2):

1. click "Settings" with the gear icon
2. uncheck "See summary charts and text response
3. click eye icon again
4. Ta-da! "See previous responses" is gone!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "see previous responses" text cannot be changed.

To remove the "submit another response" link in the new forms layout, you can go to Settings > Presentation and uncheck the box that says "Show link to submit another response".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Dec 2022

The Interface and the button locations are changed in the new Google Form.
Here's the screenshot of the exact page. Just turn off the 'View results summary'

[image]